# mvn test is not running tests - my test cases work via IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, testing, junit

I'm aware that there are multiple threads going around in regards to this I have tried for up to 3 hours so I apologise for the repetition.

All I want to do is run mvn test to have it run the Junit 5 Tests. Pressing Run on IntelliJ works but mvn test in the terminal does not.

File structure is below -

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37623164/64642711-53cf1d80-d452-11e9-9764-849d73fcc5c9.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.petrego</groupId>
    <artifactId>PetRego</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PetRego</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Returned Result in Logs -

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.petrego:PetRego >-------------------------
[INFO] Building PetRego 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ PetRego ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ PetRego ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ PetRego ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/639603/projects/PetRego/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ PetRego ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ PetRego ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.704 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-11T05:02:30+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: did you read this: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html ? And do you use the correct annotation from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` (JUnit5) instead of `org.junit.Test` (Junit4) ?

Comment: What happens when you run with the debug (```-X```) flag?

Comment: @AKSW I changed that still returning the same results

Comment: @jhell have found some sort of a conflict - investigating now. I'll be surprised if this is the issue but lets see! Is there something I should be looking for in particular?

Comment: The problem is simply you have to give junit-jupiter-engine as a dependency and nothing else...and you should check if you have correctly using the correct imports of junit jupiter and not from junit 4 ...furthermore give an test source as example...

Comment: @AKSW excuse me - I thought I had changed it. I was importing JUnit4 - super embarrassing. I apologise for wasting everyone's time. 

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AKSW suggested in the questions there is an incorrect import.

I was importing org.junit.Test (Junit4) when I should been importing JUnit5  org.junit.jupiter.api.Test (JUnit5)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the first thing you should do is check if there are newer versions of plugins.
Upgrading surefire should fix your issue, see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

Comment: I had tried the new version also. Where are you seeing version mismatch?

Comment: The logging says `[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test)`, so you're not using the most recent version.